# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException...once again

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So, I have this error in user crash report for my app. Here's the report:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
at rs.androidaplikacije.zastaveigradovi.Kviz10Hard.nextQuestionGrad(Kviz10Hard.)
at rs.androidaplikacije.zastaveigradovi.Kviz10Hard.access$1(Kviz10Hard.)
at rs.androidaplikacije.zastaveigradovi.Kviz10Hard$2.run(Kviz10Hard.java:68)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here's the mentioned code:

```
private void nextQuestionGrad() {

    flag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    dodatnoPitanje.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    if(!myDbHelper.checkDataBase()){
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();
    }

    try{ 

        mDbHelper.open();

        Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestDataGradovi(mCurrentID);

        List<Answer> labels = new ArrayList<Answer>();

        labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(2), true));
        labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(3), false));
        labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(4), false));
        labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(5), false));

        tacanOdg = c.getString(2);

        Collections.shuffle(labels);

        dodatnoPitanje.setText(c.getString(1));

        bOdgovor1.setText(labels.get(0).option);
        bOdgovor1.setTag(labels.get(0));
        bOdgovor1.setOnClickListener(clickListenerGrad);

        bOdgovor2.setText(labels.get(1).option);
        bOdgovor2.setTag(labels.get(1));
        bOdgovor2.setOnClickListener(clickListenerGrad);

        bOdgovor3.setText(labels.get(2).option);
        bOdgovor3.setTag(labels.get(2));
        bOdgovor3.setOnClickListener(clickListenerGrad);

        bOdgovor4.setText(labels.get(3).option);
        bOdgovor4.setTag(labels.get(3));
        bOdgovor4.setOnClickListener(clickListenerGrad);

        score.setText("Score: " + brojacTacnihOdgovora);

    }finally{ 
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
}
```

And part of my adapter class I'm using for this class:

```
public Cursor getTestDataGradovi(long id){
    try{
        String sql ="SELECT * FROM tblGradovi WHERE _ID = " + id;

        Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if (c!=null){
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        return c;
    }catch (SQLException mSQLException){
        Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
        throw mSQLException;
    }
 }
```

Can someone tell me where's the problem? The error line (Kviz10Hard.) is here:

```
labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(2), true));
```

Comment: your error comes from here: Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestDataGradovi(mCurrentID); Check the value of c. I bet it's null

Comment: @AsierAranbarri `c` will never be `null`, but the cursor may be empty.

Comment: don't use direct numbers to access your data. Use `c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_CONSTANT))`...

Comment: where ever you called `Cursor c` also write code `c.moveToFirst();` after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before trying to get any data from a `Cursor` object you need to iterate the result or get the first one if the cursor contains only one value. For example to iterate between all result you should do something like this :

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.rawQuery(sql, null);
if(cursor != null){
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        for(cursor.move(0);cursor.moveToNext();cursor.isAfterLast()){
            // get your data here
        }
    }
    cursor.close(); // close your cursor when you don't need it anymore
}
```

or another way to do this it :

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.rawQuery(sql, null);
if(cursor != null){
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        do {
             // get value
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close(); // close your cursor when you don't need it anymore
}
```

or if you are pretty sure that the result should be only one object depending on your sql statement you should call `cursor.moveToFirst();` before accessing anything from your `Cursor` like this :

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.rawQuery(sql, null);
if(cursor != null){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String myString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
    cursor.close(); // close your cursor when you don't need it anymore
}
```

**Edit:**

If you really want to create function like this in your database class I would do something like this :

```
public static Cursor getUserTitles(int userId){
      String sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE userId=?";
      return mDbHelper.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{Integer.toString(userId)});
}
```

**Second Edit:**

Change your `getTestDataGradovi` to :

```
public Cursor getTestDataGradovi(long id){
    String sql ="SELECT * FROM tblGradovi WHERE _ID=?";
    return  mDb.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
}
```

and add `c.moveToFirst();` , after `Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestDataGradovi(mCurrentID);`

Comment: I have imported sqlite database in assets folder. Every time I get one random row from the database.

Comment: First of all be sure that the whole database is copied properly if you are importing it from assets and after that just use the methods above to get data from your database and nothing will fail.

Comment: What do you mean "copied properly"? I guess if it works when I start the game, it's copied to my phone.

Comment: If your database has all the tables. check the edited answer how to get properly values from cursor.

Comment: I can't do that. I need to use the WHERE clause. I need it, cause once I get some value (question) from the database, I don't want it again in a single game.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you will use WHERE or ORDER BY or LIKE or anything else, this code doesn't care about your sql statement. Depending on the statement you will get results which you should 'parse' and get like this.

Comment: It depends on you. You can create static method in your database class which returns cursor or use it like this code in your game class

Comment: So if I use it in my adapter class I will have two String sql = statements? Mine, and this one, yours.

Comment: I did. Sorry mate to waste your time, but you definetely lost me. :( I don't know what is userID now. I just draw questions from database. As I said before, this db stuff is not my stronger suit, I did all this stuff using web just to make it work, I tought I did it right, but I guess I did not. Is there any way just to correct my code to make this thing work? And not to kill myself in process? :) Maybe this will help..[here's the link](https://github.com/Nabukodonosor/spojnice) where you can see my TestAdapter class, DatabaseHelper and my Kviz10Hard (game) class. Sorry once again.

Comment: userId is just a test param which is there just to show you how you can include data in your WHERE clause.

Comment: So no try and catch? Also, no checking if the cursor is null? Ok, i will try. Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking that the Cursor contains any results. You need to check the return value of `c.moveToNext()`, or check `c.getCount()` or something similar.

Comment: I don't get it. I do c.moveToNext(); in my adapter class and return cursor c. Is that not good?

Comment: No. That doesn't help you if the cursor is empty! moveToNext is returning `false`, but you aren't checking this anywhere.

Comment: So, how to correct this in my code?  This stuff in not my stronger suit I'm affraid. :(